# A problem on functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

Problem: Let $E$ be a measurable subset of $\Bbb R$ and for $t\in E$, let $x_1(t)=t$. Let $X=\{x\in L^2(E):x_1x\in L^2(E)\}$ and $F:X\to L^2(E)$ be defined by $F(x)=x_1x$. If $E=[a,b]$, then $F$ is continuous, but if $E=\Bbb R$, then $F$ is not continuous.

Attempt(Edited): Consider $E=[a,b]$, then
\begin{align}||F(x)||=||x_1x||&=\left(\int_a^b |x_1(t)x(t)|^2\right)^{1/2}\\
&=\left(\int_a^b |tx(t)|^2\right)^{1/2}\\
&\leq \max\{|t|:t\in [a,b]\}\left(\int_a^b |x(t)|^2\right)^{1/2}\\&=\max\{|t|:t\in [a,b]\}||x||.
\end{align}
Thus, $F$ is bounded imples $F$ is continuous.

For the second part, consider $$y_n(t)=\begin{cases}1&|t|\leq n\\0&|t|>1.\end{cases}$$
Then, \begin{align}||F(y_n)||=||x_1y_n||&=\left(\int_{-n}^n |x_1(t)y_n(t)|^2\right)^{1/2}\\&=\left(\int_{-n}^n|t|^2|y_n(t)|^2\right)^{1/2}\leq\left(\int_{-n}^n t^2\right)^{1/2}\leq C n.~~\{For, |t|\leq n\}\end{align}
This violates the definition of a bounded linear map for large $n$.

Now , I am lost, However, I know Holder's inequality, but how to apply here?
Also am I on right track?

Comment: Just pull pull out the maximum value of $|t|$ on $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulling out $\max \{|t|: a \leq t \leq b\}$ proves the first part. Hint for second part: Show that we cannot have $\|F(x_1y_n)| \leq C\|y_n\|$ ($C$ independent of $n$)when $y_n(t)=1$ for $|t| \leq n$  and $0$ for  $|t| >n$.

[$(\int_{-n}^{n}t^{2}dt)^{1/2} \leq C (\int_{-n}^{n}dt)^{1/2}$ is same as $2n^{3} /3 \leq C^{2} 2n$ which obviously cannot hold for  large $n$].

Comment: Thank you so much! Please have a look I have edited my solution under your hints.

Comment: @AmanPandey I have edited.